# Facebook SDK friendPickerFragment.setOnSelectionChangedListener causing error for android project

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have set up an OnSelectionChangedListener to my project as follows:

```
friendPickerFragment.setOnSelectionChangedListener(new PickerFragment.OnSelectionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectionChanged(PickerFragment<?> fragment){
            FriendPickerApplication application = (FriendPickerApplication) getApplication();
            application.setSelectedUsers(friendPickerFragment.getSelection());

            setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

This is the exact same format at the OnDoneButtonClickedListener in the facebook sdk sample app "FriendPickerSample". I am getting the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.garrenkeith.facebook.FriendPickerApplication
```

I am looking for a solution to fix the code that will add the selected user to the application when a user is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your manifest file. You probably haven't configured your `FriendPickerApplication` class in the `<application>` tag.

Furthermore, are you sure you need to subclass `Application'? From the Android docs:

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton.

Comment: I'm pretty much just going off the samples from the sdk. Pretty much a noob at all this, but I set up the application in my manifest and no more error! It's always the simplest fixes that take the longest to figure out.